# Flex mobile How to change App name?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex4.5

When i finish building my program into an app and install it, the app name (appear below its icon) is call "Main".

How do I change the "Main" into something more meaning full like "My App"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the root in your src folder, there is a corresponding xml file named after your application ending with "-app.xml" that defines meta information of your application.  Update the name property (and be sure to check filename and id as well).

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6">

<!-- Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File Template.  -->

    <!-- A universally unique application identifier. -->
    <id>com.myDomain.myName</id>

    <!-- Used as the filename for the application. Required. -->
    <filename>myFilename</filename>

    <!-- The name that is displayed in the AIR application installer. 
    May have multiple values for each language. See samples or xsd schema file. Optional. -->
    <name>myName</name>
```

Comment: what/where is the <filename> ?

Comment: At the same path as your application.  In your project, there's a "src" folder, and the xml will be there.  If you app is named "main.as", then your description file will be "main-app.xml".

Comment: hi how can add lancher icon tag in this xml file please tell me some suggestion

Comment: Look for the <icon> tag - inside <icon> you need to add <image16x16> <image32x32> <image36x36> <image57x57> <image72x72> <image114x114> <image128x128> <image512x512> to support both iPhone and iPad.